# Watching 4K videos is incredibly choppy and has graphical issues

Tags: graphics, video

I've bought a 4K video which I want to play.

I tried playing it on both the default 'Videos' application, and VLC player. Both were incredibly choppy and had graphical issues such as this:

[image]

Why isn't this working, am I missing something? I have a decent GPU (MSI Radeon R9 280X) so I expect to be able to play a video perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you have the AMD fglrx drivers installed? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: @seanlano no I have the open source X.org drivers installed, why?

Comment: I've experienced things like this before, and found that graphics performance improves when using the proprietary drives. It's unfortunate, but the open source drivers often don't match the performance. I can't point to anything concrete but [this Phoronix article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nvidia_vdpau_gpu&num=3) demonstrates the use of NVidia's proprietary video decoding vs using the CPU (which I believe is what the open source driver has to do). It's from a while ago, and it's not technically related to AMD but I'd suggest giving the fglrx driver a go at least.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was installing `vainfo` package and choosing the `VA-API` hardware decoder in VLC settings:

`All settings->Input/Codecs->Video Codecs->FFmpeg->Hardware decoding->VA-API`

Perhaps this will help someone else. For reference, I have nVidia with the latest tested proprietary driver, 1060GTX laptop and the video file in question is in 10bit 4k resolution.